# Issue Finding Required Jars Google Drive V3 Integration With Java

Tags: java, maven, automation, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to intergrate my application with google drive V3 API using the following link..

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java

I have created a simple java project and as per the given guide, added the following three jars from maven.

google-api-client-1.23.0 (1).jar

google-oauth-client-jetty-1.23.0 (1).jar

google-api-services-drive-v3-rev110-1.23.0.jar

[image: Following is the image of my application where i cannot find some libraries required.]

Am i missing any more jars that are required? or have google docs not specified a library that was required for this project to run?

P.S :- I have tried adding jars manually from web but have not found any solution.

Answer (score 0):

[image: JarsList]

Following are the list of Jars that were required to run this sample

Comment: Is this the answer you're looking for or is it the continue of your question?